# Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy: Check Comment if it contains certain string

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015

Followed https://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html

I have added the registry key and value, however unable to see the gated policy being applied.

I also have a gated check-in policy enabled, which allowed for each checkin to be built on TFS.

It is my assumption that TFS should stop you (show a warning/error based on the policy that is currently being implemented) before the gated-checkin popup is shown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi vay,  from you article you referenced the reg file adds to the registry of version 2012 of visual studio (v11) if you want this to work for version 2015 use 14.  See this site for visual studio version number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added a registry key to v14, as that folder exists within the registry. I am wondering if a restart or something else is needed.

Comment: Of Studio most likely, but if doesn't work then try the computer for sure.  You might also want to look at Jesse's post https://jessehouwing.net/tfvc-checkin-policy-support-multiple-visual-studio-versions/.  He seems to make it work with VS 2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the Check-in Policy is a warning  such as below picture. Only if there is a pending change and not meet the policy. Visual Studio will generate a row called Policy Warnings:

> The following check-in policies were not satisfied:
>
> You must .......

[image]

If you ignored the warning and insist on checking in, you will get a failure and nothing checked in.

[image]

**Only after you already met check in policy, then gated check-in dialog will pop-up** and ask you to build.  Once build passed verified , your local pending changes will finally be checked in.

[image]

---

If your customized check in policy not work, make sure it already added in Source Control Settings and been enabled.

[image]

Hope it's clear.

Comment: I don't think the check is happening on the comment. Technically what I want is the comment to start with a string(ex. USXXXXX: Insert Comment). So, if the user just enters the comment and not an associated alphanumeric text, I would like a error to appear.

Comment: Hi vay, according to your description, what you actually want is prefilling the Comment Section within the Pending Changes? There is no build-in way to do this. And I don't think you can do that the way you want. Check-in policy are one-way only in the sense you can only read the data and validate but you can't update what's in the Pending Changes dialogs.
You're not supposed to directly interact with the pending changes dialog of Visual Studio. But if you just want to make sure check in comment is mandatory, it's not hard to achieve during the check in.

Comment: I don't want to automatically fill in the comments field, but like you said, rather validate that field matches a rule set that I have defined. I have added the rules as you stated above and added the registry key as well. I supposed there maybe an external factor playing into it, not allowing the policy to be set correctly.

Comment: Yeah you may have to debug you code in vs why it's not work. Besides, if you just want to make sure there is a check in comment and since you are still working on visual studio 2015. You could also try to user power tools and there is a **changeset comment policy** , for details take a look at this blog: https://mdaslam.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/tfs-2015how-to-make-check-in-comments-mandatory/